# Google Chrome extension manifest.json plugin public permission bug?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that also uses a custom NSAPI plugin in the background page. This works great if I have the following in the manifest.json.

```
"plugins": [
    { "path": "build/debug/mypugin.dll", "public": true }
  ],
```

I want to mark this as "public": false so that the plugin can only be called by my extension. But then the plugin methods fail to get called. Cannot find much documentation around this. Seems like a bug?

I have these permissions:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": [    "tabs", 
                    "http://*/*", 
                    "https://*/*", 
                    "contextMenus",                 
                    "webRequest"],
```

Has anyone been able to set a plugin to "public":false and still have it work with a call from the extension background page?

Regards

Steve

Comment: I see the same. Too bad this looks like a dead thread.